# How to make horizontal scroll which scrolls by clicking button? Django template

Tags: javascript, html, css, django-templates, frontend

I am doing ecommerce website in django.I wanted to implement horizontal scroll of products in my website.But, I do not have any idea about this. Can someone give me an idea about how to do this?
[image]

For example, if the right button clicked, I want to show another product and remove first product in this list(like scrolling). However, I do not have any ideas? So, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check bootstrap-carousel making slider for your product items:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/

Comment: But, how to show four products at one time?

Comment: You can make a <ul> and <li> list of your products in a <div> and set the max-width to 100% or whatever; and then set the overflow-x to auto to make a horizontal slider for your products.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make arrows in each direction between the red button to make this more convenient for the user. Next, you should determine if you want to have a database of products behind your website to be able to manage your stock. You could make an id for each of your products and incrementing or decrementing it on the click of the button then change the product based on that id. In general an database is more useful for shopping websites. Another option is to make a simple carrousel to change the displayed product with bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) or by hand if you want.

As an example, I made a shopping website for my school project, which includes an bootstrap carrousel for featured products (The visual could be better I know):
Home Page: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmuBY.png)

In this code I made a function to retrieve the id of some products of the database in the carousel:

#### Carousel Code:

```
<div id="produits" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#produits" data-bs-slide- 
to="0" class="active" aria-current="true"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#produits" data-bs-slide- 
to="1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#produits" data-bs-slide- 
to="2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#produits" data-bs-slide- 
to="3"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#produits" data-bs-slide- 
to="4"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <?php
        $manproduit->getByNo(16);
        ?>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <?php
        $manproduit->getByNo(5);
        ?>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <?php
        $manproduit->getByNo(13);
        ?>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <?php
        $manproduit->getByNo(24);
        ?>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <?php
        $manproduit->getByNo(27);
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs- 
target="#produits" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon btncarousel" aria- 
hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs- 
target="#produits" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon btncarousel" aria- 
hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </div>
```

#### The get by number function code:

```
public function getByNo($no)
{
$request = $this->db->prepare('SELECT no, nom, categorie, description, prix, qte, dateParution, image FROM Produits WHERE no = :no');
$request->bindValue(':no', $no, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$request->execute();
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  while ($produits = $request->fetch()) {
    echo "<div class='form-group col-lg-12'>
              <div>
                  <a href='details-produit.php?id=" . $produits['no'] . "'><img src='img/" . $produits['image'] . "' width='250' height='200'></a>
              </div> 
              <div>
                  <a href='details-produit.php?id=" . $produits['no'] . "'>" . $produits['nom'] . "</a> <p> Prix: " . $produits['prix'] . " $ </p> 
                  <div> 
                        <p>Date de parution : " . $produits['dateParution'] . "</p>
                        <p>Description : " . $produits['description'] ." </p>
                        "; if($produits['qte'] == 0) { echo "
                        <p class='error mt-5'>Produit non disponible</p>
                        <p><button class='btn btn-primary' disabled>Ajouter au panier</button></p>
                        "; } else { echo "
                        <p><a href='panier.php?currentid=" . $produits['no'] . "' class='btn btn-primary mt-4'>Ajouter au panier</a></p>
                        "; } "
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
         ";
         
  }
} else {
    while ($produits = $request->fetch()) {
      echo  "<a href='details-produit.php?id=" . $produits['no'] . "'><img class='d-block mx-auto w-25 h-25' src='img/" . $produits['image'] . "'></a> 
            <div class='carousel-caption d-none d-md-block'> 
            <a href='details-produit.php?id=" . $produits['no'] . "'> <h5>" . $produits['nom'] . "</h5> </a> <p> Prix: ". $produits['prix'] ."</p> 
            </div>
            ";
    }
  }

$request->closeCursor();
return $produits;
}
```

The manproduit in the first code is an instance of the class ProductList witch contains all the functions to get, add and delete products by using other requests like this one.

When you click on a product that takes you to the product detail page where you may add it to the cart:
Detail Page: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71d6W.png)

Then I added the full catalogue of products sorted by the type of product:
Catalogue Page: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wXK0.png)

All of my code was made with html, css, php, javascript for the connection and registration form validation and an SQL database:
Database: [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBqAY.png)

Obviously, I cannot not show all of my code in this project because it is too long, so if you want to go further, this tutorial could help with a similar approach: PHP and MySQL tutorial: [5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIuHHXLQG1w). Otherwise, if you want to make it more simple and complete, you could use a web application by using Laravel that simplifies the code of the database connection and interactions: Laravel documentation: [6](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x)

Comment: can you share working code? that would be a high quality answer